# Flex 4 XML Attribute Binding Not Working?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

For some reason this seems to no longer work in flex 4, it used to work in flex 3...

```
[Bindable]
public var xmlTitle:String = "TEST";

[Bindable]
public var xmlData:XML = <Data title={xmlTitle}> ... </Data>;
```

I am setting the xmlTitle variable outside of the component:

```
<local:Comp xmlTitle="Some Title" />
```

I have tried with getter / setters...etc. It just does NOT update when changing, it shows the default value and never changes. Is this a known new bug in flex 4?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I've ever done that before, mostly because it's extremely bad form.  If you want to create an xml, using the XML object in mxml to create it in the declarations:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="xmlData" xmlns="">
        <Data title="{xmlTitle}">
        </Data>
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: Seems like a problem with the xmlns, when we removed that, which is a custom namespace, it works with both the attribute as well as the element.

Comment: adding a name space name:

    <fx:Declarations>     
    <fx:XML id="xmlData" xmlns:NAME="..."> 
    ...
    </fx>
    </fx:Declarations>

Solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using `{}` with XML in ActionScript **is not** data binding. It takes current variable's value in the moment of forming XML. And doesn't change it later. So this behavior is absolutely expectable.

Comment: Thanks, putting it in actionscript was really just a test because within the Declarations tag, it didn't seem to do anything at all, NOT even set the default value...any thoughts?

Comment: See the reply from @J_A_X how to perform it better way.